# gluing along a real analytic manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, fa.functional-analysis

hi,

I have a general question. Assume we have a real analytic $n-$dim. manifold $X$ and $M$ a real analytic compact submanifold of $X$ (of dimension less that the dimension of $X$, say $k < n$). Furthermore assume that on $M$ we have a real analytic $l-$form $\Omega$ ($l < k$). Let $\{U_{i}\}$ be a finite covering of $M$ by open sets in $X$ and on each $U_{i}$ we have a real analytic $l-$form $\alpha_{i}$ which restricted on $M$ is the form $\Omega$. Is it possible to use analycity to glue all forms $\alpha_{i}$ together to get one form $\alpha$ on a neighbourhood of the real manifold $M$?

Answer (score 1):

The question should be posed in this way: given a real analytic $l$-form $\alpha$ on $M$, is there a real analytic extension $\widetilde \alpha$ defined in an open neighborhood of $M$ in $X$?
The answer is yes. In fact there is a tubular neighborhood $U$ of $M$ in $X$ and a real analytic bundle map $p : U \to M$ such that $p_{|M} = \text{id}_M$ (this can be constructed by considering the exponential map of the normal bundle of $M$ in $X$ with respect to a real analytic metric on $X$, see [Morrey](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1970048?uid=3738296&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21100782327261)). Then put $\widetilde \alpha = p^*(\alpha)$.

Comment: is the extension then unique? can one use analicity for uniqueness ?

Comment: this is actually where I am interested in .

Comment: The extension is not strictly unique, perhaps is so up to real analytic homotopy rel. M (depending on which analytic metric you pick). May be, is unique the real analytic homotopy class rel. M of the germ of such forms (but is a very "weak" uniqueness).

Comment: what do you mean by "real analytic homotopoy rel. M" ?

Comment: The fact that there is a real analytic family $\widetilde\alpha_t$, $t \in [0,1]$, connecting any two such extensions (possibly up to passing to a smaller neighborhood), such that $\widetilde\alpha_t = \alpha$ in $M$ for all $t$.

Comment: aha I see. but isn't it possible to glue these forms together, as I mentioned in my initial question, in order to obtain a global form along M? by analycity? 

Comment: The usual way to glue together forms or tensors is by means of partitions of unity. But these are only smooth, not analytic. Also, there are no reasons for the forms $\alpha_i$ you consider to match in the intersection.

Comment: but the forms $\alpha_{i}$ agree on $M$ with $\alpha$ which is real analytic. hence on the overlaps two forms $\alpha_{i}$ and $\alpha_{j}$ agree on M and by the Identity theorem they agree on the overlaps (maybe make the sets $U_{i}$ smaler). Is this right? If not, where is the breakdown ?

Comment: and also the forms $\alpha_{i}$ are real analytic.


Comment: No, the analyticity does not imply that coincide in a neighborhood. Locally the forms are determined by some functions (the components). Think that if you have an analytic function $f$ defined in a neighborhood of 0 in $R$, if $f(0)=0$, then $f=0$? Of course no.

Comment: yes but if the set of points where $f$ is zero has an accumulation point, ten by the Identity theorem it follows that $f$ is zero. And so was my arguement, on the overlaps restricted to M, say the set $U_{i} \cap U_{j} \cap M$ has obviously an accumulation point (it has a lot of points) and on this set $\alpha_{i}$ and $\alpha_{j}$ agree (its $\alpha$) and they are also real analytic, so they have to coincide on sufficiently small neighbouhoods, right? Is this argumentation true ? If not where is the breakdown, again :) ?

Comment: OK, the argument fails in dimension $> 1$. Look for instance at the function $f(x, y) = x$. You have $f(0, y) = 0$ for all $y$ but $f \neq 0$.